# C++ Regex - Complexity Error

Tags: c++, regex, url

I am trying the following piece of code in order to validate a url file:

```
if (std::regex_match(url, std::regex("^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|bmp|png)$"))) {
     // Do stuff if url is valid
}
```

But I get the following error:

> regex_error(error_complexity): The complexity of an attempted match against a regular expression exceeded a pre-set level.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Your regex is not properly escaped, try use to a raw string literal `R"(…)"`.

Comment: The _complexity_ error comes from this part `"\.)+"` which resolves to this `.)+` where the dot means any character.